# Openshift 503 Service Unavailable (No server is available to handle this request)

Tags: web-applications, openshift

I have upgraded my Openshift to Bronze plan, but my application often stops, i don't know if it is idling or is it an error.
here is the result of my tail comand (rhc tail -a chat) :

```
    [ALERT] 072/061558 (19871) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 072/061619 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 17ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 072/071558 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10002ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 072/071558 (19871) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 072/071616 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 14ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 072/081559 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 072/081559 (19871) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 072/081620 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 25ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 072/091559 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 072/091559 (19871) : proxy 'express' has no server available!

==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2016-03-11T08:50:43.872042 #413940]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-12T03:32:32.503225 #126323]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-12T04:35:24.084358 #389943]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-12T09:56:39.495738 #237958]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-12T09:57:25.706140 #243996]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-12T10:09:35.606396 #310247]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-13T05:09:12.261879 #509228]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-13T05:10:54.370695 #518248]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-13T05:13:16.307865 #8582]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2016-03-13T05:15:20.794716 #19888]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160312110958 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAa5eqAMRWOOH5yKnzkeFBwh17TZP6r0.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAaU8aCjHUcPwwUkW1kxIW28y-ZJQrNB.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAc9ZswDIdVFliTYACG8RdSd-sikMPir.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAeHTvxg6_Zf2IIJhwMMXTNyi5tv0_0L.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAga_a_b2hmkXTdz-WpKjp14LtNp7kwW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAkQf3yPMQIhqQmWL0ejlJxtzZCB_167.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAlqTgW20UHIq1gTFifiIEky5SI1xX9G.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAltgEkRYG40tuS300xxBc8d9XCmfAfI.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAlvSJfTfUf6daE3DGyJLVp7eTLDKewl.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QAogazchsTMrLGoGKaXkeYGM9VNs9laO.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160312111027 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB1sGAg-eYDoEdBRO8OrzHuFjQv0xycQ.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB52rpACR6a3pzYCCNIwERz-TrSc7v3W.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB6My5a9tsHiGHM8MJ79DKUJ_rsZUX2A.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB71uyNlWRyX2bDe3lRgQP7g0o1GrPEP.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB7FO4-FvYutojnVf83rmK_VrLhnEdaB.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QB7cc0sW46u6IEOqVjN8_iUs9UllIzJN.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QBB8fCWvWSVdl8UL7G-8YSMifzbRkAIZ.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QBBOpjmz10osRl1S5UEv4MFWP22g2fYW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QBCQcE_oSylsKlGwuxNZufFoLYoktret.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/QBDGdmWWQGHKznohOrrNp9jc-hVRcp5u.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313121018 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aSxnsglsybWgSGWnKtqOjuS3XNNAgzDm.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aSz4YkPoXPFLNzbG0lhehjky5KK-Y4Yc.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aT5QSskGEbeqxmugv4afcnQkFQFnzBUa.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTAkfAjDTm14Yim1I6WsM8bAZJ44VfKo.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTD4amB_tWgs2yosd2hM6_IJzSRMEdHR.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTEKHIwhZUuqGY_RiCi67ytQIxqRq1RI.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTQ7xvAJ8Aks1cvKfZfBx4zhQgctA2oQ.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTUmB5RsslxlLM3YLD4MK7v1OUSHvOTR.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTYJ0U3HE37-OYtQ5Zq5lVbz8VsEjahd.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/aTZOzTmcasSCLom7TfqwtFma7GPogj4F.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313061549 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBd38eOggoinwWF5ZIsoVPDTbvRtBXZM.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBgbDzVsn_Y8B4buCWui-XyC6bV6ohDW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBhHTTyqVnNn24KNL13mcj7_ofHZnuaS.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBhop3ULulUsWidkVVWIxb9VyF_uHeK2.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBjel64XFcgk1vIloKqTCFMlI-L9w4_c.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBjlxSGoTTF_AFcJWmRQ3niKU72PsfZL.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBpYGbKltbgS9yK91PYrIyJUGkuMoxSf.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBqAdWR74ceuTI46NPUr-pKDLOjI3vzl.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBql4AiFW_fI2DtvaqJEED2MsGhdshtU.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/UBzNBjUs_tzQMnZmkb3odXNivUFn4fCk.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313071543 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/N9RJHszkdj79AsPg5ah2odeyeu7qj4DE.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/N9hwuy76dSA4nYcGrbM9kcaLf_JLNGP_.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NAfSWOka4JbcYbqkyIlovkk_TapSkbQ_.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NC6iq5tRzja2srhuOKqNqc4W2BG0VvKo.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NCgJm8zJ9ZKTe5zPHV54L8-_0voTr6sJ.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NCoAdjzSN1Qd7mmxdvkaBXjFOhZhdqSz.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/ND7fB5NuF5D7Fc-gRshjYGHWKihXruNk.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NCo_waDGfewsHunp-3gallc5r06TEm3G.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NDsUte5BZFqpxh5vPDiJ8Ybm9fJj3v4q.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/NGFfYzsiHnaEHuK1NNSjk8WxKT7-Msvi.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313071601 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/ZlhrD23LZZviPPFlkPqJnFBw-mIa0Yka.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zlij2WCRyCady9KjUWwT7rVAIVEAfmGa.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zln5EbvlYzg6wAi86WjRPxHE9Lk7pviN.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/ZlnEDH8sBoTBI71ilTUgv0alRGqoZbaN.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zlnfi6bI6zW8p_G6PXob8_lstvZAr_RV.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/ZlufyJDYQSbPB6PL4dx1AzgMDy3Gbfv7.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/ZlwNiX0Z7bLSk110kjBPPEC94bbOPtSy.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zm-aamhc2hz8TR_55HQwR1PLK52EK_LK.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zm0bkBxETyboiYIPbWTzwev-pSndR7Im.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Zm5S0vYsAOQXHhtuAvSQXTFAt87QGkR_.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313081555 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RMwR32Pe04IZ0sn0eYUfEIbGRCscRK2E.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RMyERVzTu16M7VRkFZeTr0-oIVo8iuiv.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RMyyjYxSHYQ1CKbdvHMoBeWQqeOTbAMd.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RMzOekpUQCfM79Cyeaky0gRIMU_mNhOd.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RMzzk2qQ6iJ9Gh7gSOeZqrn_KwnUrHjK.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RN-YFQsi8xLttxQfcZQ2-FHSt0s-MrTS.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RN0tqsi7gl_3FDAj63eHOJoapuNCujRD.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RN6IbinpvyweJ7cGNPmRRyJYIM0T9AYy.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RN7kOaEVKBHMpPa5c2ngThF6sPtujdKP.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/RNED1Ea0Fu-H7ZRn3LCz9Rv2GEYSo3_k.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313091546 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bmtyhY_ZOM2FjbPtQdOpEISmSBAurBWD.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bmuv6rxUmza4MiZQ4sIQ0k-PnZgnmRtt.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bmv4nLZHAsQ7Y6HYek9ggr913jYYcPW6.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bmyr_cJ_qjOOvkSRMtDyPwnAAkIyfyJ1.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bn8NgiSUKKE1TmC59dQe4vmZMJAvnw_4.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bn8RuJeg7At0JRZa2qptJpkh08bCSmC9.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bn8iIwEO85OZg4p-Pp5P2G9Pp4GqY6Cq.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bnB0INN4bzf784gJziA8i9g5voV5TZgC.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bnDUFhsBUlG3E65-_qn4ocyFAqsh9vdK.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/bnElkqNLbKXmxMWgwSrRkWOX4uHW1b_d.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160313091607 <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xfx5lUY8EFLwdY_6hBgMdiRVtPSlfIyf.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/XfxvWJnXq8OGbtVRZft_UWEoP9v6KgWi.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg-fJwBp5-BfsvFG_9c4QmGcOzw4pGCu.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg1F62c7rvuJ_CMcuXwVTUZ163A4A_nr.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg08OLs_YRo5vEzbCpnLXLrtqNQNRgGu.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg2-k-E7XHmxfn5KUVDPPg2c8NDXSNii.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg3iF3FHpoxplggdY8X2SZYsNyWxbVt3.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg5_p3oZjc_RrR9PiTJIYXZVtFsmByZj.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg6KXwguybHMOcbInMWAzsRhn9nzlYLd.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/Xg6pxgMgrMNE2CS3PhRK3Fh4G-LgsmbE.json'

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7X0bszs45WhTG4WgadOEOss1IdZfHgh.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7Z5bzMMm-xblQi6Y6l0v3Z3UxXoHkT8.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7aCet6U4OEgimOZrmSwCcwMkAKnTfwD.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7b5InQ3CBxLUYIg2Uf6fbcFnGDdtNW4.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7ekj0alzwwforVFqcaoT8-J7nyCJ-_3.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7k_feyy3Q_NjjCDkCUjsp1yYT4kGETM.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c7ugawvFg5e_6zTlnqfKAElKi3Hf7Gto.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c85BName9nFKcJA4sWFMYNUHLBexBtuK.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c86ORYNbpt6HMO1EhtNLt4O7FHChX5vF.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EMFILE, open 'sessions/c8DIfGdYesh9F28nzstvDajZq9IcbFTs.json'
```

I don't know if it is an error or just application idling.
Sorry for my bad english and thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a scaled application on OpenShift v2, you will get a 503 from haproxy anytime there are no backend servers passing the health check.  So when you see messages like this:

`[WARNING] 072/081559 (19871) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 072/081559 (19871) : proxy 'express' has no server available!`

That means your backend servers are all failing, and the reason given there is a timeout.  Your health check URL must respond within 10 seconds to be considered healthy.  I don't know what's wrong with your nodejs application, but idling is definitely not the problem.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, but when  i restart my applicaion (rhc app restart -a chat) it works again.
I can't see any log issue about timeout, can you tell me how to see what is causing the timeout ?